# client side freezes when requesting JSON from server

Tags: java, ajax, multithreading

I have a Java program that will freeze during the rush hour currently. I am looking for the reason. Right now, my idea is that it is because some of the codes are not AJAX, so it will hangs in there when requesting JSON object from server during rush hour (Internet speed is slow during rush hour). But I am not very sure that it is not AJAX though. I cannot paste all the codes here because it is related to company's property, so I am going to write some piece of codes/pseudocode. The program uses the following to do the request.

```
 URL url = new URL("http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/");
 URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
 BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection .getInputStream()));
 String inputLine;
 String content = "";
 while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) { 
            content += inputLine;
        }
 in.close();
 json = new JSONObject(content);
```

The above codes are some snippet of the program where I think it causes the freezing. My question is that, This piece of code does not seem to use any AJAX and it is not multithreading, right? So it hangs in there (freezing) when the Internet connection is very slow? I am not very experienced about this. Please help.

If you do not think this is the main reason that causes the freezing, what could be the most possible reason for this kind of problem in general speaking.
Thank you in advance.

**Edits/Update:**

1. My program is a swing program that runs in client side. There is no
   real server side codes for this application. The URL address is a
   3rd party server that provides some kind of data that the program
   needs. I did not see the program uses any threads. It is basically core Java without using any threads as I see, and I am not very familiar with multi-threading, so I am not sure. (The program is not written by me, it is written by some former programmers) That is why I am considering that maybe it did not use other threads to run this server request when it should be.
2. What I mean by freezing is that **the UI will freeze for a few seconds during the rush hour when it try to run some specific functions**. The above code I wrote is some snippet from those functions. After the UI freezes for awhile, it then works as expected in the rest. However, in non-rush hour, it works like a charm.
3. Specifically,  **BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
   InputStreamReader(conection .getInputStream()));**  is what I think
   that causes the problem. Could anyone confirm that?

Comment: Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/), you are blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, which is preventing to from updating the UI and responding to new events

Comment: Does it "freeze" forever? Or does it "freeze" for a while and then come back?

Comment: @LeeMeador it freezes for awhile and work as expected

Comment: I didn't see where you said anything about the user interface. How does the user know it is frozen? What's on their screen/browser/console/whatever?

Comment: @LeeMeador Please see updates. it makes my question more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- All asynchronous methods like HTTP POST/GET,  implement in separate Thread. User don't interest to see what your application does in background.
- In addition, its not good practice to use String for appends, like  jlordo says, use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.

  StringBuilder buff= new StringBuilder();
  while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

  ```
      if(!"".equals(line).trim){
          buff.append(line).append("\n");
       }           
  }
  ```

  in.close();
- You can add timeout to your session to be sure that application doesn't stuck at all.

**[EDIT]**

Regard to question changes, I don't think that

> BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conection .getInputStream()));

it's your problem.

You can try to do followed flow but I still thinks about separate Thread with GUI Thread

```
InputStream is = conection .getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line = null;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: In fact, @Joey, the problem may be that your program isn't multithreaded when it should be. Any operation that takes a long time should be run on its on thread, and the event thread should only be used for UI updates.

Comment: @chrylis Please see updates. it makes my question more clear.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a `SwingWorker` thread to do the call to the server. That way, when it is busy, the UI won't freeze.

However, remember, you won't see the resulting changes on the screen that the new data would provide until the new data arrives.

See [Oracle SwingWorker JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)

Tutorial with [example similar to yours](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html)